# make openJPA caching only chosen tables

Tags: java, caching, jpa, openjpa

How can I set  openJPA cache so that it works only for chosen entities, maybe I need use some annotaion over they?
my persistence.xml contains:

```
 <property name="openjpa.DataCache" value="true"/>
 <property name="openjpa.RemoteCommitProvider" value="sjvm"/>
```

but thats settings works for all my entities(tables), so i want to cache for example only that table:

```
@Entity(name = "IsoCountryCodes")
@Table(name = "ISO_COUNTRY_CODES", schema = "ANALYSIS")
@DataCache(timeout=120000)
public class IsoCountryCodes  implements Serializable{
   ....
}
```

But @DataCache doesnt fix it, its only set the timeout of cache saving.

**UPDATE:**
I cannot use openJPA 2.0 cause my project deployed on WebLogic 10.36 and have provided KODO openJPA 1.3.
Also i try to include only chosen entities by adding property:
  **property name="openjpa.DataCache" value="true(Types=foo.bar.FullTimeEmployee)"**

but got this error:

`org.apache.openjpa.lib.util.ParseException: There was an error while setting up the configuration plugin option "DataCache". The plugin was of type "class kodo.datacache.KodoConcurrentDataCache". The plugin property "Type" had no corresponding setter method or accessible field.  All possible plugin properties are: [CacheSize, EvictionSchedule, FailFast, NAME_DEFAULT, Name, SoftReferenceSize].`

Can you help me?Maybe you know other ways to exclude or include entitites from caching, maybe with  Ehcache usage?

Answer (score 1):

`<property name="openjpa.DataCache" value="true"/>`

That enables the L2 cache for all Entities. If you are using jpa-2.0, try adding `<shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>` to turn the cache on. Also, replace the `@DataCache` annotation with a `@javax.persistence.Cacheable` annotation.

Comment: when i try to add in my persistence.xml
<shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
i got error element is not allowed here

Comment: maybe its cause my jpa version <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             version="1.0">

Comment: That would do it. That is also why I mentioned that you need to be using jpa-2.0.

Comment: i cannot use openJPA 2.0 cause my project deployed on WebLogic 10.36 and have provided KODO openJPA 1.3. Updated my question, maybe you can help me

Comment: Since you're using WebLogic, I'd suggest opening a support ticket.